# Trying to extract value with Regex

Tags: regex, vb.net

This is the text:

```
"{\"step_naAme\": \"\", \"nonce_code\": \"HGtDXNmPhb\", \"user_id\": 1545816852, \"is_stateless\": false}"
```

I just want to extract `HGtDXNmPhb` and `1545816852` without the rest. I tried:

```
dim text as string = regex.match(text=fromstring,"""{\""step_name\"":\""\"", \""nonce_code\"": \""(.*?)\"", \""user_id\"": (.*?),\""is_stateless\"": false}""").groups(1).value
```

the response was empty every time. please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, if you know for fact that the values will always be in the same place in the array (make sure you escape the original string properly first of course):

```
    Dim strString As String = """{\""step_naAme\"": \""\"", \""nonce_code\"": \""HGtDXNmPhb\"", \""user_id\"": 1545816852, \""is_stateless\"": false}"""
    
    Dim strSearch() As String = Regex.Split(strString, "\W+")

    Debug.Writeline(strSearch(3) & " " & strSearch(5))
```

**Result:**

```
HGtDXNmPhb 1545816852
```

Comment: Thank You Bro Very Much It Worked, I'm Very Thankful.

Comment: @vjlu Happy to help. Thank me with your upvotes & Marking as best answer. :p

Comment: and how can i do that , i really have no idea

Comment: @vjlu just click the Up arrow, and check mark next to the answer ;)